# how to change button image when button pressed

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I want to show different image for button after user taps that button ...
How would I do that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define images for different states of button press. Here is a brief example:

```
UIButton *submitbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
// position in the parent view and set the size of the button
submitbutton.frame = CGRectMake(165, 20, 149, 39); 
[submitbutton setTitle:@"Submit Booking" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Add image to button for normal state
UIImage * btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SubmitBooking-normal.png"];
[submitbutton setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Add image to button for pressed state
UIImage * btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SubmitBooking-pressed.png"];
[submitbutton setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];


// add targets and actions
[submitbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitBookingButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a some parent view.
[someview addSubview:submitbutton];
```

There are probably other things you would want to customize. You can read more about these options [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

another way is to choose the button and assign the image you want then from the utilities bar change the state config to Highlighted then assign the on click image

see the link for screen shot below

[screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RHQGGVkTouUElIY1pDQkpZNDQ/view?usp=sharing)